# CSS grid creates a new box for each html tag

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-grid

I have this CSS part for my site:

```
*{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

}
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid div:nth-child(odd){
    border: black 2px solid;
}

.grid div:nth-child(even){
    border: black 2px solid;
}
```

And I want to have four boxes, but it just creates a new box for each HTML tag, instead of placing it in the corresponding box, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InGnQ.png).

*The low poly part of the screenshot is the visible part and the four boxes are the boxes which should contain the content*

Here is the template: [Click](https://codesandbox.io/s/532pzv8m6l?fontsize=14)

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is? What do you want to achieve/what is the expected result, and how does it differ from the current situation?

Comment: @jensmtg at the moment it looks like there's a new grid box for each html tag, even though they are all in the same div. I want to have four divs/boxes with the content in the corresponding box and not under the whole site or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the height and width specifications on the grid itself, and it should behave more as expected.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.grid div:nth-child(odd) {
  border: black 2px solid;
}

.grid div:nth-child(even) {
  border: black 2px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're applying `height: 100%` to every single element in your code.

```
* {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}
```

This forces all elements to take 100% of the parent, and block elements stack vertically.

You don't need to do this. It's overkill.

Remove the code above and just add this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  height: 100vh;
}
```